# Disappearing Javascript onClick Box, New to JS

Tags: javascript

So I created a page that was supposed to have a box open up onClick. While this worked in a vacuum, when I upload it to the page it seems like when I use the button, it will initially show the content, then, it "reloads" the page, and then hides the content again.

The snippet of Javascript I used was:`

```
<script>
function showVet() {
var x = document.getElementById('vetinfo');
if (x.style.display === 'none') {
x.style.display = 'block';
} else {
x.style.display = 'none';
}
}
function showSust() {
var x = document.getElementById('sustinfo');
if (x.style.display === 'none') {
x.style.display = 'block';
} else {
x.style.display = 'none';
}
}
function showGuarantee() {
var x = document.getElementById('guaranteeinfo');
if (x.style.display === 'none') {
x.style.display = 'block';
} else {
x.style.display = 'none';
}
}
</script>`
```

Then in the HTML referenced if like this (just one of the sections):

```
<div class="section feature bt10">
<h3>Holistic Veterinarian<br>Approved</h3>
<button class="HPbutton hidden-sm" onclick="showVet()">Learn More</button>
</div>
```

You can view the page here:
https://www.onlynaturalpet.com/CompanyInfo/about-us-our-honest-promise.aspx

I'm pretty new to javascript, so I might have just messed something up. When I tested the page in local environment it was fine,I'm not sure where I went wrong!

Comment: On first glance this may be a simple fix: remove the parentheses from your onclick attr in the html.

Comment: @7yl4r You seem to have overlooked that event handler attribute text in HTML is compiled into a function before being added to the DOM. For the compiled function to call `showVet` the parentheses are required.

Answer (score 1):

The default type of a button is "submit". The button which calls `showVet` in the click attribute is inside a form, so it submits the form which reloads the page.

Submission can be prevented by changing the button (in line 692 of the linked page)  type to "button":

```
<button type="button" class="HPbutton hidden-sm" onclick="showVet()">Learn More</button>
```

which does not submit a form it may be in.

Comment: Thank you, I actually solved it (probably poorly) by adding return: false after the "showVet"; string.

That is probably not the best way to do it. I will try both of your comments and get back to you, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: That will work, but it's actually a hack from HTML3 to use submit INPUT elements as general purpose buttons, prior to the introduction of BUTTON elements. I recommend specifying `type="button"` for general purpose BUTTON elements in HTML4 and later.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I will try implementing your comments and update with the proper code once done.